# xhtmlrenderer optimizations :css taking too much time

Tags: css, pdf, xhtml, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I'm using flying saucer xhtmlrenderer to generate  pdf from xhtml. The issues i'm facing with it is that **xhtmlrenderer is taking too much time to generate pdf when css files are large** or there is too much css. I tried to generate pdf with and without css. And the results were as expected. It took nearly **3 sec without css and 50 secounds with css**. Can anybody tell me some way to **reduce generationn time**. I tried to optimize my code but since xhtmlrenderer is external lib, i can't do much to optimize it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you're after. An alternative to XHTML Renderer? A way to reduce your CSS?

Comment: xhtml renderer solve most of my problem except it taking substantial amout of time for pdf generation, so i am satisfy with respect to its results but not with its performance.I have to convert complex webpage having lots of stylesheets at server side to pdf. Thus if you know some other alternative which can do better than XHTML renderer than please share. I can't reduce my css as it is part of UI. I tried some of css compression technique but its not that worthy. Hopefully now you understands details of my problem.